# What is the python/pandas equivalent to R smartbind()

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

I have been trying to piece together what the equivalent to `smartbind(df1,df2)` in R is in Python pandas. Looking at the smartbind() documentation I am not sure exactly how to do the same thing in python. Would it just be a `df1.merge(df2)`, or would it be `df1.merge(df2, how='left')`? thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`ggtools::smartbind()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/smartbind) can handle cases where "column names don't match", maybe

```
df = df_a.append(df_b, sort=True)
```

will help you. See [`pandas.DataFrame.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for the pandas `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], axis=1)
```